# is 0xF0000000 negative or positive?

Tags: assembly

I am working with ARM assembly, and trying (again) to undestand a jump table. The linked image is a jump table entry from a canon rebel t1i firmware dump. In this case, R0 (i refer to it as arg1) is some number that is >= 0x10000091 (as explained in the attached picture).

I am trying to figure out how 0xF0000000 is used here. The only thing I can think of is that it must be some negative number... as that's the only way I can make sense of things here. The way I worked it out in the comments was assuming that 0xF0000000 = -268435445, but as I explained there it doesn't seem to work...

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUW54.png)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter whether it's positive or negative.

If you step through with possible values of R0 you get this:

```
R0          ADD...      SUB...
10000091 => 00000091 => 00000000 => branch to loc_FF1CC924
10000092 => 00000092 => 00000001 => branch to loc_FF1CC928
10000093 => 00000093 => 00000002 => branch to loc_FF1CC92C
10000094 => 00000094 => 00000003 => branch to loc_FF1CC930
10000095 => 00000095 => 00000004 => branch to loc_FF1CC934

anything else will fall through  => branch to loc_FF1CFAEC
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be either positive or negative; it depends on the context. For cases where the value is assumed to be a signed 4-byte integer, it equals -268,435,456. For cases where the value is assumed to be an unsigned 4-byte integer (such as for addresses), it equals 4,026,531,840.

Here's [Google's calculations for the negative value](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=0xF0000000+-+0x100000000+in+decimal&pbx=1&oq=0xF0000000+-+0x100000000+in+decimal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=10761l22575l0l37l36l1l0l0l0l255l5578l7.17.11l35&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c3c1825d9c672113&biw=1200&bih=649).

Here's [Google's calculations for the positive value](http://www.google.com/search?q=0xF0000000&btnG=Search#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=0xF0000000%20in%20decimal&pbx=1&oq=0xF0000000%20in%20decimal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4145l8827l0l15l13l2l0l0l0l272l1469l4.6.1l11&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c3c1825d9c672113&biw=1200&bih=649).

Answer (score 1):

`0xF0000000` is just a symbol.  It can represent anything.

As a hexadecimal representation of a 32-bit number, it can be either positive or negative, depending on whether the number is signed or unsigned.

As a hexadecimal representation of a signed twos-complement 32-bit number, it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Negative, I think.  The left-most bit would be the sign bit. ("I think" because I need to check the representation ARMs use, but hardly anything uses the other possibilities any more.)